Why is my thread blocked by this try block?
So I am self-taught and green on handling requests, but it seems to me that in the case of no request body, the BufferedReader should output null if I call .readLine() again after running this kind of while loop:
while (!(line = br.readLine()).isBlank()){ some code here }

So I have done this to successfully load up method and headers into variables, and everything is working swell until I decided to add a bit of code to detect (not yet handle) the presence of a request body
try {
    if ((body = br.readLine()) == null) {
        System.out.println("body = " + body);
        reqLog.append("- Request body: false\n");
    } else {
        reqLog.append("- Request body: true\n");
    }
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

The code above blocks my thread - my web browser patiently waits while nothing visually happens on my server. Everything within this block executes however when I cancel the browser connection. Even the System.out.println(body = null) then pops up in the terminal, before the error for an aborted connection takes over.
Removing the try-block above solves everything.
I am super grateful for a pointer toward proper detection of a request body as well!

It makes a difference how you set up your BufferedReader, including the underlying readers and streams.  You have not disclosed that.  It also depends on server configuration.  If the server is using persistent connections then it will not close the connection to indicate the end of the response, so you cannot expect an attempt to read past the end of the response headers to immediately return null.  You need to parse the headers to determine what to expect in terms of a response entity.

Also, HTTP is fundamentally byte oriented, especially HTTP headers.  Any HTML payload consists of character data, but you can't be certain of the encoding before you parse the response headers.  Even then, the HTML itself can specify its own encoding.  All this is to say that it is questionable to read a raw HTTP response with a Reader.  You probably should be using an InputStream instead.  An InputStreamReader (only) wrapped around that might not be too bad, but a BufferedReader is a problem if you find you need to switch encodings.

And you should consider using existing tools instead of re-inventing the wheel.  There are existing libraries for doing what you're trying to do, and at minimum, it makes little sense to avoid using the standard library's HttpURLConnection class, unless your purpose is to study the details of the HTTP protocol.

Please format your code neatly when posting here. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat room.

Any chance that a newline was not sent in the request?  Your readline might be waiting for it.  Reading a block of bytes (as mentioned by @JohnBollinger) is a better practice.

HTTP 1.1 supports persistent connections where a client does not close the connection but sends another request after it received an answer for the current request. In this case waiting for br.readLine() to return null will block the server from answering the request. In the case of persistent connections your server must read the body by reading as many bytes as sent as the body length instead of waiting for a closed connection.

Thank you, @JohnBollinger, for really constructive feed-back! I was not sure how much code to include (not wanting to spam the thread), but I get that everything is connected and I might be in a bit too deep - so yes I have ended up reinventing the wheel because being self-taught it is hard to find tutorials that show how to connect features beyond just what a future in isolation does. I shall look into every piece of advice that you have provided, and with the changes to my code the issue in question may have solved itself! Again, thank you so much!

Thank you, @BasilBourque, this is my first post on Stackoverflow and I am eager to follow expected conventions. Would you like to explain how exactly my code was badly formatted? Perhaps a specific example on what to do different?

@T-Stone Look at the edits by Gray, who generously cleaned up your code.

Thank you, @Gray, for a good suggestion! I am only so far handling the initial http request from Chrome to obtain the html, so I trust Chrome to not be at fault. Reading blocks of bytes seems to be my next study - I am sure my code will be better for it and hopefully this issue will be solved in the process!

An [MCVE] would improve this Question.

@BasilBourque Thank you, I think I understand now - I shall do my best going forward!

@BasilBourque If the code required to reproduce a problem spans a lot of classes, what would be the best approach to provide it? Copy paste every class into the post?
